# How to create intro sliders like Google Docs App [Img inside]?

Tags: android, user-interface

In the new [Google Docs Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs), the app has an intro slider view in which it shows the different steps of how to use the app - I like it and want to do something similar for my app.

Are there beautiful looking open source libraries to do this? I can think of the following approaches only:

1. [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview)
2. I guess I could do it using Tabs, and adjust the look and feel accordingly.

Any other (beautiful) alternatives?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using ViewPager.

For each click on "next" button you can change the page in ViewPager.

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/

Answer (score 3):

(This question is slightly old, but here goes:)

Another open source Android library that I found that does exactly this (and fairly easily) is [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro).

It enables creation of intro sliders that look identical to Google's more recent intro sliders:

[image: Intro slider created with AppIntro]

vs

[image: Google Plus Collection intro sliders]

Their [wiki](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro/wiki/How-to-Use) and their [readme](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro#appintro) nicely describe exactly how to use it.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, I'll only leave here an alternative used by Phonograph: https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-intro